# Filter Search Results in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, performance, scala, playframework

I need to filter search results in play framework. Lets say by price range. What i could think of is to call the controller with the user selected price range and show the result in view, Which i don't think is the best solution to the problem.

Please answer the following questions:

1. Is there anyway i can refine the search results in view itself using Scala (template engine), It would be my best solution, As i already have results, I can save a Service call.
2. If i had to call the controller, Is there anyway i can declare public variables in Play framework, So i can save the first search result in public variable and use it next time. If this is the answer, I need to know if it is a good practice to use public variables in Play framework performance wise.

**If not play i at least need a java based solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - no.

Play does not have any abstraction layer for filtering, paging, etc. You should do it by yourself. Submit filter form to controller and perform another search based on submited data.